# How to parse XML in Python - retrieve elements within tree/root

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am currently writing a Python script for some web application testing and am running into some issues. I’d classify myself as a beginner in Python so explanations behind possible solutions would be much appreciated.

The goal of this script is to take in an xml file, which contains website request and response details, and parse it out to give me easy to ingest data that I can run validation checks on.

My sample XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>
<items exportTime="Mon Mar 14 14:28:18 EDT 2022">
  <item>
    <time>Mon Mar 14 13:59:37 EDT 2022</time>
    <url><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/sw.js_data]]></url>
    <protocol>https</protocol>
    <method><![CDATA[GET]]></method>
    <path><![CDATA[/sw.js_data]]></path>
    <extension>null</extension>
    <request base64="false"><![CDATA[GET /sw.js_data HTTP/2
Host: www.youtube.com
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.youtube.com/sw.js

]]></request>
    <status>200</status>
    <mimetype>JSON</mimetype>
    <response base64="false"><![CDATA[HTTP/2 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 17:59:34 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="response.bin"; filename*=UTF-8''response.bin
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy-Report-Only: same-origin; report-to="ATmXEA_XZXH6CdbrmjUzyTbVgxu22C8KYH7NsxKbRt94"
Permissions-Policy: ch-ua-arch=*, ch-ua-bitness=*, ch-ua-full-version=*, ch-ua-full-version-list=*, ch-ua-model=*, ch-ua-platform=*, ch-ua-platform-version=*
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version
Server: ESF
X-Xss-Protection: 0
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

)]}'

[["yt.sw.adr",null,[[["en","US","US","75.188.116.252",null,null,1,null,[],null,null,"","","CgtaVS1FWnl4ZTJEZyiGhb6RBg%3D%3D","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)",1,"2.20220311.01.00","Windows","10.0",null,null,null,"https://www.youtube.com/sw.js_data",[],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,2,1,"vip\u003d142.250.190.14,server_port\u003d443,client_port\u003d57491,tcp_connection_request_count\u003d0,header_order\u003dHCUAREL,gfe_version\u003d2.764.3,ssl,ssl_info\u003dTLSv1.3:RNA:T,tlsext\u003dS,sni\u003dwww.youtube.com,hex_encoded_client_hello\u003d130213011303c02cc02bcca9c030cca8c02f009fccaa00a3009e00a2c024c028c023c027006b006a00670040c02ec032c02dc031c026c02ac025c029c00ac014c009c0130039003800330032c005c00fc004c00e009d009c003d003c0035002fc008c01200160013c003c00d000a00ff-00-00000005000a000b000d00320010001100170023002b002d0033,c\u003d1302,pn\u003dalpn,ja3\u003d2d5bd942ebf308df61e1572861d146f6,rtt_source\u003dh2_ping,rtt\u003d41,srtt\u003d80,client_protocol\u003dh2,client_transport\u003dtcp,gfe\u003dacorde13.prod.google.com,pzf\u003dWindows NT kernel [4:118+10:0:1460:mss*44/8:mss/nop/ws/nop/nop/sok:df/id+:0] [generic tos:0x20],vip_region\u003ddefault,asn\u003d10796,cc\u003dUS,eid\u003dhoIvYvCZG42E8wes0aCgCw,scheme\u003dhttps,location\u003dord37s32,metro\u003dORD",null,null,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,null,"CIaFvpEGEP_3rQUQmOqtBRC3y60FEPX4rQUQ1vitBRDI0_0SENi-rQUQkfj8Eg%3D%3D"],null,null,2,[],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"America/New_York",null,null,["US",2],null,null,[],"Chrome","99.0.4844.51",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],[]],null,[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,null,null,0],null,[null,null,null,null,null,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,[1647280774452302,176365571,201449727],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,[]],[null,"IhMIzqigi5fG9gIVAyCDCh3/4AEM"],null,null,null,null,null,[]],"AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8",null,null,"","QUFFLUhqbnREclEzblJmc25GVF9XSXQ1dFZQSm9sRGlmQXxBQ3Jtc0tuU3huS1RoOHQyaFlqN0dLdm4wcGMweXp0OURWQU5RbEJKRko1TlhGYjBoZ3N1Nnpla3QxUFRkN19uaWxoQVZTV0FRUGh0cUw2ckRWbmh5bGhxYkRjNFc2cUREbjB4MnFxMEpval9HUXNZeWU5d1Ztaw\u003d\u003d","CgtaVS1FWnl4ZTJEZyiGhb6RBg%3D%3D"],"Vf114d778||"]]]]></response>
    <comment></comment>
  </item>
  <item>
    <time>Mon Mar 14 13:59:14 EDT 2022</time>
    <url><![CDATA[https://www.google.com/client_204?&atyp=i&biw=1440&bih=849&dpr=1.5&ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ]]></url>
    <protocol>https</protocol>
    <method><![CDATA[GET]]></method>
    <path><![CDATA[/client_204?&atyp=i&biw=1440&bih=849&dpr=1.5&ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ]]></path>
    <extension>null</extension>
    <request base64="false"><![CDATA[GET /client_204?&atyp=i&biw=1440&bih=849&dpr=1.5&ei=Z4IvYpTtF5LU9AP1nIOICQ HTTP/2
Host: www.google.com
Sec-Ch-Ua-Arch: "x86"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Full-Version: "99.0.4844.51"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform-Version: "10.0.0"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Bitness: "64"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Model: 
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
X-Client-Data: CJDnygE=
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Referer: https://www.google.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

]]></request>
    <status>204</status>
    <mimetype></mimetype>
    <response base64="false"><![CDATA[HTTP/2 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
Bfcache-Opt-In: unload
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 17:59:10 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 0
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

]]></response>
    <comment></comment>
  </item>
</items>
```

The XML seems a little strangely formatted around the headers but I would like to just extract the request host and the response headers from both items (google and youtube) and put them into a list. I have made some progress but I'm having trouble running a for loop to get *just* these values for both items. I'm not sure if I'm able to call the tag  to get this data or what the best way to go about this is.

My current code is below:

```
tree = ET.parse('googleandyoutube.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
new = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8')

#below loop kind of works in getting about the right information but it does not do it for both items
for item in root.iter('item'):
    print(response.text)
```

result:

```
HTTP/2 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

HTTP/2 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: extra code at end of first website response below

```
X-Xss-Protection: 0
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"

)]}'

[["yt.sw.adr",null,[[["en","US","US","75.188.116.252",null,null,1,null,[],null,null,"","","CgtaVS1FWnl4ZTJEZyiGhb6RBg%3D%3D","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)",1,"2.20220311.01.00","Windows","10.0",null,null,null,"https://www.youtube.com/sw.js_data",[],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,2,1,"vip\u003d142.250.190.14,server_port\u003d443,client_port\u003d57491,tcp_connection_request_count\u003d0,header_order\u003dHCUAREL,gfe_version\u003d2.764.3,ssl,ssl_info\u003dTLSv1.3:RNA:T,tlsext\u003dS,sni\u003dwww.youtube.com,hex_encoded_client_hello\u003d130213011303c02cc02bcca9c030cca8c02f009fccaa00a3009e00a2c024c028c023c027006b006a00670040c02ec032c02dc031c026c02ac025c029c00ac014c009c0130039003800330032c005c00fc004c00e009d009c003d003c0035002fc008c01200160013c003c00d000a00ff-00-00000005000a000b000d00320010001100170023002b002d0033,c\u003d1302,pn\u003dalpn,ja3\u003d2d5bd942ebf308df61e1572861d146f6,rtt_source\u003dh2_ping,rtt\u003d41,srtt\u003d80,client_protocol\u003dh2,client_transport\u003dtcp,gfe\u003dacorde13.prod.google.com,pzf\u003dWindows NT kernel [4:118+10:0:1460:mss*44/8:mss/nop/ws/nop/nop/sok:df/id+:0] [generic tos:0x20],vip_region\u003ddefault,asn\u003d10796,cc\u003dUS,eid\u003dhoIvYvCZG42E8wes0aCgCw,scheme\u003dhttps,location\u003dord37s32,metro\u003dORD",null,null,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,null,"CIaFvpEGEP_3rQUQmOqtBRC3y60FEPX4rQUQ1vitBRDI0_0SENi-rQUQkfj8Eg%3D%3D"],null,null,2,[],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"America/New_York",null,null,["US",2],null,null,[],"Chrome","99.0.4844.51",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],[]],null,[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,null,null,0],null,[null,null,null,null,null,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,[1647280774452302,176365571,201449727],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,[]],[null,"IhMIzqigi5fG9gIVAyCDCh3/4AEM"],null,null,null,null,null,[]],"AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8",null,null,"","QUFFLUhqbnREclEzblJmc25GVF9XSXQ1dFZQSm9sRGlmQXxBQ3Jtc0tuU3huS1RoOHQyaFlqN0dLdm4wcGMweXp0OURWQU5RbEJKRko1TlhGYjBoZ3N1Nnpla3QxUFRkN19uaWxoQVZTV0FRUGh0cUw2ckRWbmh5bGhxYkRjNFc2cUREbjB4MnFxMEpval9HUXNZeWU5d1Ztaw\u003d\u003d","CgtaVS1FWnl4ZTJEZyiGhb6RBg%3D%3D"],"Vf114d778||"]]
** end of first response **
```

Edit: pasted original XML

Comment: put missing part directly in XML - this way we can simply copy it

Comment: I'll just paste the whole original XML, thought cleaning it would make it easier but clearly not the case

Answer (score 0):

First of, when asking questions, it is extremely helpful if the input data (XML) is working, otherwise its cubersome getting it to work.

In your case if I understand correctly, you need two kinds of function. The `list(xml_element)` returns all `children` of the element, in case of a `list` all `items` in case of an `object` all `keys, values`.
With `element.find("name_of_subitem")` you can access a specific element by name.

See working example below with a reduced version of your code.

```
s = """
<items>
  <item>
    <time>Mon Mar 14 13:59:37 EDT 2022</time>
    <url><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com]]></url>

    <request base64="false">
    </request>
    <status>200</status>
    <response base64="false">
        <![CDATA[HTTP/2 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

]]>
    </response>
  </item>
  <item>
    <time>Mon Mar 14 13:59:14 EDT 2022</time>
    <url>
    </url>

    <request base64="false"></request>
    <status>204</status>
    <response base64="false">
    <![CDATA[HTTP/2 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

]]>
</response>
  </item>
</items>
"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
items = ET.fromstring(s)
for item in list(items):
    resp = item.find("response")
    print(resp.text.strip()
```

Result

```
        HTTP/2 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN


    

    HTTP/2 204 No Content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-9KQUw4dRjvKnx/zTrOblTQ==' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: sorry about the XML, tried to clean/trim it up a bit but just made it harder to work with. That code seems to have done the trick for me - thank you! The first item seems to have a bunch of extra code at the end of the headers (edited original question to include that code block for reference). Is there an easy way to get rid of this in a universal way that would handle any extra characters like this in the future? I'm not even really sure what is is

Comment: Add ```strip()``` to remove that

Comment: where exactly should I be adding that? It doesn't seem to be removing it. Tried ".strip()" after my original string and ".strip()" applied to resp.text but I'm still getting all of those extra characters